# SQL Query for subject prerequisite

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, phpmyadmin

Sorry i made another question because my last question is too confusing.

EDIT: My Current QUERY

```
UPDATE student_subject 
  JOIN subject_bsit
    ON subject_bsit.subject_id = student_subject.sub_id
   SET enrolled = 1 
 where student_subject.student_id = 1235 
   and student_subject.sub_id = 1
```

What i want to happen is.

**Student_id=1235** is trying to enroll **subject_id=5** so that statement must not happen because **subject_id=5** has a Prerequisite to **subject_id=1** or programming 1

But if example in the **student_subject** sub_id 1 and Enrolled=1 meaning the student finish the programming and already enrolled now the **student=1235** can now enroll the subjectid=5

I don't have any idea how to this query . Thank you so much.

```
THIS IS THE TABLE

    "student"

    -----------------------
    |studentID | FullName |
    -----------------------
    |1234      | John    |
    |1235      | Michael |
    |1236      | Bryce   |

"subject_bsit"

    -----------------------------------------
    |subject_id| subject_name  |  pre_id    |
    -----------------------------------------
    |    1     | Programming 1 |    0     |
    |    2     | Networking    |    0     |
    |    3     | Algorithm     |    0     |
    |    4     | Physical Educ |    0     |
    |    5     | Programming 2 |     1       |

This is the Junction table to connect the 
    two now.

"student_subject"

    ------------------------------------------------
    | student_id | subject_id | Grade   | Enrolled |
    ------------------------------------------------
    |   1235     |      1     |    0    |     0    |
    |   1235     |      2     |    0    |     0    |
    |   1235     |      3     |    0    |     0    |
    |   1234     |      1     |    0    |     0    |
```

Comment: Think about what it is that you want to get. You want the records from `student_subject` where the `student_id` matches your student and `Enrolled` is 1 and the `subject_id` is equal to the `pre_id` of the `subject_bsit` where the `subject_id` is the one for the subject you want to enrol in.   If you're having trouble writing a SQL query then it's usually because you don't have a clear idea of what the query has to do, so work that out first. Pick up a pen and paper and write down, in plain language. You can then write code to implement it bit by bit.

Comment: Hi, I already have my SQL query but i am having a problem because of the junction table and too many connection i will update it with my query.

Comment: And delete one or other of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments in line.

```vb
Private conString As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub EnrollStudent(StudentID As Integer, SubjectID As Integer)
    'Question Does Subject have a prerequisite?
    Dim Prerequisite As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(conString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select pre_id from subject_bsit 
                                        where subject_id = @subject_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = SubjectID
            cn.Open()
            Prerequisite = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    'Answer - No, It is OK to enroll student there are no prerequisites
    If Prerequisite = 0 Then
        InsertEnrollment(StudentID, SubjectID)
        Return
    End If
    'Answer - Yes there Is a prerequisite
    'New Question - Has the student passed the prerequisite?
    Dim PassingGrade As Integer
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(conString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select Grade From student_subject 
                                        Where subject_id = @subject_id 
                                        And student_id = @student_id", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Prerequisite
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cn.Open()
            PassingGrade = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    'Answer - Yes, student has a passing grade.
    If PassingGrade > 0 Then
        InsertEnrollment(StudentID, StudentID)
    Else 'Answer - No, student does not have a passing grade in prerequisite.
        MessageBox.Show("Student cannot enroll because of prerequisite.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub InsertEnrollment(StudentID As Integer, SubjectID As Integer)
    Dim query = "Insert Into student_subject (student_id, subjectId, Grade, Enrolled) 
                Values (@student_id, @subject_id, 0, 1);"
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection(conString)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = StudentID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@subject_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = SubjectID
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Successful enrollment")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    EnrollStudent(1235, 5)
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Typo here...

```
If PassingGrade > 0 Then
    InsertEnrollment(StudentID, StudentID)
```

This should be

```
If PassingGrade > 0 Then
    InsertEnrollment(StudentID, SubjectID)
```

The second argument is SubjectID

Comment: Hi, it is working if i only try to add a subject with no prerequisite. but i try to add the ID of subject that has a prereisite this is the error.

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`csais`.`student_subject`, CONSTRAINT `student_subject_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sub_id`) REFERENCES `subject_bsit` (`subject_id`))

Comment: Hi. Thank you again.  Can you help me again ?? I run on another problem. What if the passing grade is only 1,2 and 3 and 5 is equals to Failed and there is also another "INC" means incomplete so i need to set the passing grade as string but Cint function is only for Integer ?

Comment: Sorry. Thank you so much.